# jQuery Mobile - displaying an image, lost the header and footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an app where one page (on a multi-page document) is nothing but a picture - one picture. However, when I go to that page, I can't see the header or the footer. As a result, I have not way to navigate away from this picture page.

Here's the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="asbuilt" data-fullscreen="false">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href='#details' data-role='button' data-icon='bars' class='ui-btn-left' data-iconpos='notext' data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Listing</a>
    <h1>Asbuilt</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <img src="{{ w.systemID.asbuiltFile.docfile.url}}">
  </div>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery mobile but is it possible you have a CSS z-index issue on your hands?

Comment: Hmmm, how would I check that? The header/footer displays nicely everywhere else, it's just the page with the image.

Comment: Can you post your CSS if you have one? That would help a lot.

Comment: The CSS is the standard jQuery mobile CSS, nothing beyond that.

Comment: This is your code with the default jQuery mobile js and css included. http://jsfiddle.net/Vj22e/ Do you see your problem in the jsFiddle?

Comment: No, I don't see the problem in the fiddle. However, it isn't really a great example is it? since the page on the fiddle is divided up.

Comment: It was a bit of a long shot I admit. Can you try to adding position:relative; z-index:1; to ui-content in the jQuery mobile CSS and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Unfortunately, still no dice after adding that to the CSS. I feel like the jQuery Mobile libraries are treating the image special, and just making it fullscreen by default.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do much else without looking at the actual code or a jsFiddle.

Comment: Ya, thanks for the help though :)